# Make a scene a 3D texture in THREE.js (3D Render Targets)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm looking at the THREE.js example located [here](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_rtt) and wondering how to prevent the 'flattening' of scenes rendered as textures. In other words, the scene loses the illusion of having depth when set as a `WebGLRenderTarget`.

I have looked everywhere, including in THREE.js documentation, and have found no mention of this kind of functionality, probably because it would put a significant load on the user's processor unnecessarily (except for in very particular cases). Perhaps this is possible in pure WebGL, though?

**EDIT:** Downvoters - why is this question poor? I have done significant research into this matter, but since I'm new to WebGL, I can't exactly spout senseless code... How do I improve my query?

Comment: (1) Why don't you modify the example and use a perspective camera instead of an orothgraphic one, and use the render target as the texture for a plane, instead of for a sphere. That is what happens in a movie theater. See http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Camera-Texture.html (2) There are no unnecessary "significant loads" involved here.

Comment: Thanks for the response! (1) I understand what you're saying (and have tried it), but that doesn't prevent the 'flattening'. In the example I cite, the curvature of the projection on the sphere is somewhat misleading. It would seem that WebGL only renders the 2D *illusion* of depth on projected surfaces (and for good reason, which is why I mentioned the processor load). When the projected surface rotates relative to the camera, the illusion disappears, and you can tell that the rendered surface is much like a movie screen, rather than something with real, 3-dimensional depth.

Comment: Your example does actually give me a good idea, and I may just be able to post an answer to my own question soon enough.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about... Maybe someone else can help you, if you are unable to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use screenspace projections instead of UV projections if that makes sense. Given your tv example, the screen would have the UV points that do get transformed as you move the camera around. You want something that stays put, ie. no matter how much you move, you're looking at the same thing. I'm not sure how this is done without shaders, but in fragment shaders you have gl_FragCoord

Comment: I will do some experimentation with this and get back to you. Sounds like it might work better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because THREE.js "flattens" every scene it renders, all that's needed is a change of perspective (relative to the main camera of the main scene) to maintain the illusion of depth in render targets. Here's a skeleton of something that would do that:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    rtScene = new THREE.Scene(),
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( ..... ),
    rtCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( ..... ),
    rtCube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1), new THREE.MeshSimpleMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff }),
    rtTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, format: THREE.RGBFormat }),
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: rtTexture }),
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1), material);

function init() {
  //manipulate cameras
  //add any textures, lighting, etc

  rtScene.add( rtCube );
  scene.add( cube );
}

function update() {
   //some function of cube.rotation & cube.position
   //that changes the rtCamera rotation & position,
   //depending on the desired effect.
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.clear();
  update();
  renderer.render( rtScene, rtCamera, rtTexture, true );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

init();
animate();
```

I assumed in my code that `camera` would remain stationary while `cube` rotates around the y axis. Each face has its own updating instance of `material`. The update() function for each face is a bunch of trigonometric gibberish that can be derived easily with the law of cosines. I will post a jsFiddle example as soon as I have my local working properly.

Comment: "In other words, the scene loses the illusion of having depth when set as a WebGLRenderTarget."

What does this mean? A render target can store many different things on one end, and on the other, you are looking at the contents of a render target on your screen whenever you work with three.js. What depth loss are you talking about?

Comment: This link might be useful: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: @pailhead That's exactly the point, WebGL never renders depth, only an illusion of it (drawing things in 2D in such a way that they look like they're in 3D). Problem with that is that for any object using a `WebGLRenderTarget` not aligned with the camera of the principal scene, the render target looks like a television screen, not like something with actual depth (and for obvious reasons - you don't **always** want depth on a render target). To fix this, you simply manipulate the camera within the `rtScene` to maintain depth.

Comment: That link did help me understand a bit more about how THREE's cameras work, thank you! My question relates to a similar illusion to the illusion of a pyramidal field-of-view, so it's relevant to this discussion.